# Converting KML to shapefile via ogr2ogr including all attributes

Tags: shapefile, kml, ogr2ogr

Here is the example KML file I am using:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <name>My Golf Course Example</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Club house3</name>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <phoneNumber>554545454</phoneNumber>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-111.956,33.5043</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I have named it `input3.kml`.

I put it, and ogr2ogr in the same folder, then I run this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output3.shp input3.kml
```

After that, I open up Quantum GIS and add vector layer, then add `output3.shp`.

Then I find the `output3 layer`, right click and open attribute table. How come only two attributes show up? (Name and Description)

Comment: You have name, visibility and phonenumber in the input. So what is inside the description field in your output?

Comment: There are only two fields when I view the resulting shapefile's attribute table, name and descripto. For name, it is as specified, for descripto, it is NULL

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the driver currently only works fully one way (i.e. writing TO kml).  It currently expects a Description field in the KML data and uses that for its attribute, but truncates the name to 'Descriptio' because of the shapefile's DBF field naming limitation.

However, there is a version of the KML driver [in development](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/22127/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/libkml) that will do what you want (so I guess it is not included in your version of ogr).  BUT, you will need to re-format your KML using ExtendedData tags to wrap your... um... extended data.

Comment: The LIBKML driver with ExtendedData handling is now incorporated in GDAL Version 1.9.2 onwards, OSGEO4W packages, MS4W and Qgis Master.