# Convert shapefile to KML on QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml

I want to convert a shapefile to a KML using QGIS. When I do it, the output I obtain is without attributes. And I want a similar product as it is provided by shape2kml of zonum solutions.

Comment: To answer your question, we will need more information about the specific KML file. A related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36696/editing-a-kml-file-or-converting-kml-to-editable-format-with-attributes?rq=1

Comment: I have a shapefile of lines, and every record is a line. So, the kml I want needs to have the name of each record. And the procedure on QGIS I use to obtain that kml is saving as an exporting as kml.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS is actually using ogr2ogr command to do the conversion. you can run it directly like `ogr2ogr -f KML output.kml input.shp` in terminal